# Vermont Castings propane stove flame is normal then "explodes" then goes back to normal

Tags: stove, propane

My Vermont Castings Propane stove was working fine yesterday. Today when it goes on, the flame is fine, then it bursts to a large flame for a second and then returns to the normal flame. Then it starts all over again. Anyone know what the problem is? Thank you!

Comment: I don't think this is quite the same since you have a normal flame, though if the flame is interrupted I might have a answer.   We have a Gas Stove that does this. Kinda blows the oven door open from time to time. Its the igniter that catches the gas on fire. The ignition element is like the old stove heating coil. It is taking longer to get up to temperature and this releases a bit of gas before it is hot enough to light. Gas buildup causes a bit of an explosion, then goes normal. Oven reaches temp, then gas shuts off, then does it all over again to get it back to temp.

Comment: A few guesses: clogged orifice, clogged air-mixture intake holes, faulty gas valve or knob. Insure the combustion air intake is open and that the flue is clear.